# contact form submit not responding

Tags: php

I am having a problem with the contact form and when I am trying to submit the form, it's not responding and please help me to solve this issue.below is the code

HTML:

```
   <form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" 
    class="contactForm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 form-group field">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" data- 
                rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="span4 form-group">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" 
                data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="span8 form-group">
           <textarea name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data- 
           msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"> 
           </textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" 
             value="sendmessage">Send message</button>
```

Please find the below php code for the submit form and please give me the solution on how i can solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
    //  $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];
          }

       $to='contact@****.my';
       $subject='Contact Form';
       $message="Name: " .$name."\n"."email: " .$email."\n"."Subject: " 
      .$subject."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$msg;
       $headers="From:".$email;

      if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      echo "<h1>Your message has been sent. Thank you!"."".$name.", We Will 
      Contact you shortly</h1>";
      }
     else {
      echo "Something went wrong!";
       }
```

Comment: Your button has no name and you never close the form

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your form and didn't gave your submit button a name so your php can't work

```
<form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post" 
    class="contactForm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span4 form-group field">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" data- 
                rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="span4 form-group">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" 
                data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validation"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="span8 form-group">
           <textarea name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data- 
           msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"> 
           </textarea>
              <div class="validation"></div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit"
             value="sendmessage">Send message</button>
</form>
```

and you forgot to close this sentece change it from

```
$message="Name: " .$name."\n"."email: " .$email."\n"."Subject: "
```

to

```
$message="Name: " .$name."\n"."email: " .$email."\n"."Subject: " ;
```

Comment: I have been closed form (</form>) and I have changed what you mention but the success message not appearing when I click after submit.

Comment: No I didn't get any errors and when I click submit there is no response

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg=$_POST['msg'];
```

must be

```
$msg=$_POST['message'];
```

and

```
.$subject."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$msg;
```

must be

```
$subject."\n". "Wrote the following: "."\n\n".$msg;
```